# reverse engineering: DB tables to class diagrams (1 to many | many to one mapping)

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, uml, class-diagram

Is there any open source tool that can help me generate UML diagrams(class diagrams) from DB.
I want that if i point it to a DB(mysql) it should generate all the diagrams.

AM looing for a open source tool.Can any one suggest one

Answer (score 0):

Try [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/), formally DBDesigner. It has a "Reverse Engineer Database" mode.